# Troubling figuring out one part of this script

Tags: bash, awk

I'm completely new to this, so I think this is a fairly easy question.

I have the following script which was given to me to go through our logs and pull out information:

```
awk '
match($0, /"username":"[^"]*"/) {
        split($3, d, "@")
        user = substr($0, RSTART + 12, RLENGTH - 17)
        split(user, e, "@")
        c[e[2] "," d[1] "," e[1]]++
}
END {   for(i in c)
                printf("%d,%s\n", c[i], i)
}'      mycompany.log | sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4
```

What this script does is goes through the log entries, and any entry that corresponds to a username it grabs the date, username, organization and the number of unique entries for that user on that date.  I pretty much understand how it works to get all of these values except the number of entries per user (can't figure out where in the script it does this).

Basically right now the output is sorted in columns:

number of entries, organization, date, username

like this:

```
609,organization,05-22,someuserfromthatorganization
```

and I want this:

```
organization,05-22,someuserfromthatorganization,609
```

But as I mentioned I'm unsure how/where in the script this number is calculated so I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Why do you have this tagged with `c`?

Comment: Can you show a sample input file?

Comment: It's counting the number of entries per user with `c[...]++`.

Comment: If I understand your question, you just want to swap the printout. You can change this line from `printf("%d,%s\n", c[i], i)` to `printf("%s,%d\n", i, c[i])`.

Comment: Ok thanks, this answers what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associative array `c` contains the count of entries for each user on a date. `e[2] "," d[1] "," e[1]` concatenates the organization, date, and username. This is then used as the key in the `c` array with `c[e[2] "," d[1] "," e[1]]`. Finally, the `++` increment operator makes it count the repetitions of this.

At the end it prints the contents of this array.